# android touch input bug

Tags: java, android, touch, libgdx

I'm trying to make a game in which an object moves when a finger is dragged across the screen. In the main loop, I update the object's position based on the finger's motion.

Moving the finger a certain distance on the phone should move the object the same distance. This works on a Nexus 7, but on a Droid X (Gingerbread), the object doesn't move as fast as the finger. For instance, if I drag my finger all the way across the screen, the object only moves half that distance. The motion also feels unpredictable (sometimes it moves farther and sometimes it only moves a little). What could cause this?

I'm using libgdx. In the main loop I add dx and dy to the object's x and y.

Here are the touch events (I'm storing all fingers on the screen in an array and only accessing the first one). sp is a temporary vector.

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TOUCHPOINTS; i++) {
        if (touchIDs[i] == -1) {
            touchIDs[i] = pointer;
            if (i == 0) {
                sp.x = screenX;
                sp.y = screenY;
                camera.unproject(sp);
                prevX = sp.x;
                prevY = sp.y;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    int location = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TOUCHPOINTS; i++) {
        if (touchIDs[i] == pointer) {
            location = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (location == -1)
        return false;
    for (int i = location; i < MAX_TOUCHPOINTS - 1; i++) {
        touchIDs[i] = touchIDs[i + 1];
    }
    touchIDs[MAX_TOUCHPOINTS - 1] = -1;
    if (touchIDs[0] != -1) {
        sp.x = Gdx.input.getX(touchIDs[0]);
        sp.y = Gdx.input.getY(touchIDs[0]);
        camera.unproject(sp);
        prevX = sp.x;
        prevY = sp.y;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    if (pointer == touchIDs[0]) {
        sp.x = screenX;
        sp.y = screenY;
        camera.unproject(sp);
        dx = sp.x - prevX;
        dy = sp.y - prevY;
        prevX = sp.x;
        prevY = sp.y;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a bit of trouble going through your code, however I have some things which may be useful to you, since I once built a touch scrolling system.

Libgdx already has a built in function for tracking movement of touches.

Gdx.input.getDeltaX()
Gdx.input.getDeltaY()

Those functions will produce a value that represents the change in distance. So you could simply add this value to what you use to store the position of what you wish to scroll.

I hope this helped.